# Latex PStricks \rput cannot place text in the right place

Tags: text, latex, pstricks

I have tried the example given at [pstrick \rput example](http://how-to-pstricks.blogspot.com/2012/09/rput-most-offen-used-pstricks-command.html).

The link has a picture which shows the expected results. However when I use the same code, I see a picture below:

[image: my result].

You can see the placement of the text is incorrect. I used the exact same code as in the example.

What's wrong with my latex or pstricks?

Comment: Are you compiling with latex > dvips > ps2pdf or xelatex? Not pdflatex? [What version of the packages are you using](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13304/5764)?

Comment: thank you Werner, the latex > dvips > ps2pdf  sequence solved this issue for me (not xelatex)